# Andengine: What happened to ITexture?

Tags: android, andengine

I'm trying to use the GLES1 version of the texturepacker extension. It refers to an interface:

```
org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture;
```

*This is no longer part of the main Andengine GLES1 code base.* I want to be able to use the texture packer extension, and update it, but I don't know what this interface is or does. What has it been replaced with?

A related note: 
Texturepacker extension also refers to:
org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.PixelFormat;

which has also gone missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/master/src/org/anddev/andengine/opengl/texture/ITexture.java